# AWS classic ELB conditional port forward?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

There is a classic ELB and six instances were added, say A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2. The following shows Port configuration/listeners,

```
8000 (TCP) forwarding to 8000 (TCP)
9000 (TCP) forwarding to 9000 (TCP)
4430 (TCP) forwarding to 4430 (TCP)
```

And I need

1. 8000 (TCP) forwarding to A1 and A2 only
2. 9000 (TCP) forwarding to B1 and B2 only
3. 4430 (TCP) forwarding to C1 and C2 only

Can this be possible?
Or can network ELB do it?

Comment: Your title says Network LB, but text says Classic? Which one is it?

Comment: Just corrected it. It's classic, but I'm open to use network if it's possible.

Comment: The only choices you have are ALB (Application LB for http/https) or Network LB.  So I guess you should try and NLB.

Answer (score 2):

With CLB, you sadly can't do it. You can create multiple listeners, but you can't chose which listener applies to each instance.

But you can do this with one **NLB**. This will require **three target groups**, one for each port and corresponding set of instances. You can associate all three target groups with the corresponding listeners in the NLB, while the instances will be registered with their target groups.

Comment: Just tried the create NLB wizard, which seems to only allow to create one target group?

Comment: @ca9163d9 The remining ones you have to create yourself, using Target Groups menu option in EC2 console.

Comment: I created a test nlb and it works. But I haven't had a change to test it in QA yet due to some company policy issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use a network load balancer.

Classic load balancers do not distinguish between groups of backends.  New load balancers, Application (ie http based listner rules) and Network (ie IP based rules), support listeners with different target groups behind.

Of the two, ALB is the preferred load balancer.  You can have up to 100 rules, and AWS will give you a free TLS certificate with up to 50 different domain names in SAN.  so you can host multiple sites (on the same port), distinguish between different target groups via hostname, headers, etc, and then route traffic accordingly.  You can use security groups to allow traffic.  I understand them to support all the normal stuff like web sockets.  They also do http2, which is a lot more efficient for users.

NLBs don't support HTTP level routing, instead routing by IP level attributes.  They can still do TLS.  They also don't support security groups, so you can't use an SG to identify the target of traffic, which is a might inconvenient.  They work well for services that aren't HTTP.

Comment: My company doesn't let us use ALB yet so I had to use NLB or classic. The service API has TLS/SSL so I probably doesn't need the free TLS certificate.

Comment: You probably don't.  Your company can continue to pay for its own certificate and rotate every year or two, or use let's encrypt or something.  ACM certs are probably more secure from the perspective that employees cannot access them, but typically many employees have root.  Anyhow, very common to terminate original tls connection at the instance.

Comment: Actually 4430 is for SSL/TLS connection. And I selected TCP instead of SSL to avoid configure the TLS certificate configuration part. Can this cause any problem?

Comment: perfectly acceptable to terminate the TLS stuff at the backend and specify TCP through the load balancer.  works fine, just more work and money